# Dynamics 365 Installation Error when it needs to create groups in OU

Tags: installation, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-2016

I have 2 virtual servers with Microsoft windows server 2019, and my DB is SQL server 2019, and my reporting server is 2019 as well. I want to install CRM v9 on-premise with an administrator user, and I gave that user every deligation in OU, and this user is a domain admin. But I faced an error that said: Action Microsoft.CRM.Setup.Server.CreateCrmGroupsAction Failed. The server is unwilling to process the request. I have checked every aspect of my user role and everything in my servers, but I didn't find anything. please help me as soon as possible

[image: My Error]

Comment: See if there is a detailed error in the Event Viewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while and many searches, I found my problem in permissions of my server because my ad was not a master server, and it can't create a group. After changing the ad server, my problem was solved.